# Canonical isomorphism between finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I want to ask is there a canonical isomorphism between two same finite dimensionality Hilbert spaces.

My intuition is telling me no, there is an isomorphism, but not canonical. The reason is because there is no fixed canonical choice of basis. Is my argument correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$